# Cosmos DB - Stored procedure QueryDocs is not working - Racing condition

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos DB - Stored procedure, 'CreateDocIfItDoesNotExistOrUpdate()'.

1. Query for a specific doc by filter text
2. If it exists, update the doc
3. Else, create the doc

We get updates from multiple client; so we call the stored procedures for the same doc many times within milliseconds..

Scenario:

1. Query for the record01, it really does not exist. It created the record01.
2. Within 10 milliseconds, query for the same record01, it says not exist as it could not discover the doc, 'record01'. It created the record01 with new 'id'.

I know that stored procedure does not allow two executions on a doc within a partition. With that design\ promise of Cosmos DN only, I thought of building this logic. But it fails at a big time due to this failed promise.

Consistency of Cosmos is always 'STRONG'.

```
async function createDocAsync() {
        var isAvailable = await checkIfDocExistsAsync(currentFilter);
        if (_responseData_ != null) {
            return "EXISTS";
        }
        if (isAvailable) {
            await createDocumentAsync(doc, undefined);
        }
    }
```

```
async function checkIfDocExistsAsync(currentFilter) {
        var queryText = "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.currentFilter = '" + currentFilter + "' r.isDeleted = false";
        var responseQueryDocs = await queryDocumentsAsync(queryText, undefined);
        if (responseQueryDocs.feed.length > 0) {
            
            return "Exists";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried to reproduce the contention by sending load of requests. Design promise of stored procedures is honored by not allowing multiple executions on same partition but query consistency is not honored.

Comment: Did you try using Upsert?

Comment: I see, upsert\ replace is working. But query-doc operation in the next run does not see the record which was upserted in the previous sp execution. By ACID, I should see the record if it passes the upsert ops, correct?

Comment: Why do a query at all?

Comment: I query for the doc to check if it exists or not. If available, then patch doc. Else, create the doc.

Comment: With strong consistency, it has an immediate read latency of ~10-20 ms. Even if I use upsert doc, I might have worked on older version if I have read the doc within 10ms of last write operation. With this latency problem, I am afraid about data integrity as I may read the snapshot which is not latest.

Comment: Running a query to check for the doc is not necessary when using Upsert. Same thing in a single request. If you're worried about Concurrency, use the etag. You may also want to take a look at Partial Document Updates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update

Comment: PS: Strong consistency has zero impact on latency.

Comment: Limitation in our design is, we use GUID for id field which is random; at times, there are two instances trying to upsert same document with different GUIDs. If there is no collision detection like checkIfDocExists(), it upserts both documents with different GUIDs. We could have chosen same relative, consistent and strong id field but it was too late to change it as 'id' field is linked everywhere.

Comment: So stored procedures are scoped to a logical partition. Is the "currentFilter" property your partition key here? You are correct this should work but needs to be an in-partition query.

Comment: One thing that occurred to me is you could try defining a unique key on the container using a combinations of properties. If you have properties that are always unique for the same message, this might work for you.